# Irritated by upper bounds pretending in adverts that they mean something "guaranteed to keep your baby dry for up to 12 hours"

Tags: phrase-meaning

To me the meaning is clearly that the baby will remain dry for up to 12 hours. I don't see why it is irritating?

Comment: I don't think the irritation is with the meaning, but with the validity.

Comment: I saw this on tweeter with many other examples of Irritated by upper bounds pretending in adverts that they mean something "guaranteed for up to" statements

Comment: Doesn't it just mean that some condition will remain true for up to some upper bound?

Comment: Sure, but do you think that it's a valid claim, or do you think it's nonsense?

Comment: Well, they are claiming to "guarantee" it, right?

Comment: Sure, but just because someone guarantees something, I don't necessarily believe them. Do you suppose there's any basis for the claim? Do you think you'll get your money back if your baby is wet after 11 hours an?d 30 minutes? Or do you suppose it's just an adman's phony pitch? The language is clear, but the claim is clearly bogus.

Comment: The irritation for me is claims like "save up to 70% or more". 70% is meaningless in that context, but I see it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"for up to"* part is a classic example of [weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word). They can't guarantee that the product will keep your baby dry for 12 hours so they (allegedly) add the weasel words so the meaning is still conveyed but the makers can't be sued for claiming it. If you don't notice weasel words, then I guess it isn't irritating and you just assume your baby will stay dry for 12 hours. If you do notice them, then they become irritating as they render the claim useless; it's equally valid to claim that a carrier bag is "guaranteed to keep your baby dry for up to 12 hours", as even 10 minutes still falls in the range "up to 12 hours".

Comment: The example in your link: Up to sixty percent..." (so, 59%? 50%? 10%?) made it clear.

Comment: Read literally, what they are guaranteeing is that their product won't keep your baby dry for more than 12 hours.